# Library for optimizing / parameter scanning a method

Tags: java, mathematical-optimization

I have several java classes which implements a quite complicated (non-linear) business logic. Basically the user provides several (numeric) input parameters, and the application computes a scalar.

I would like to do a parameter scan on the input data, that is I would like to know what parameter values create the maximum output value.

The easiest and most time-consuming method would be to create some simple loops with "small" steps on the input parameters, and constantly check the output one.

But as I said, this takes quite a long time; there are several mathematical solutions for this problem (e.g. Newton-method).

My question is; are there any free/open source JAVA libraries which provide this parameter scanning funcionality?

Thanks,
krisy

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to adjust [OptaPlanner](http://www.optaplanner.org/) for this. Call your business logic in a `SimpleScoreCalculator` and wrap the returned scalar in a `Score` instance.

Make sure you use at least `6.1.0.Beta2` as that supports `IntValueRange` and `DoubleValueRange`.

As for optimization algorithms: if the variables are few, integer and small in range, "Branch And Bound" can work, guaranteeing you the optimal solution (but much faster than Brute Force).

Otherwise, you'll need to go with a limited selection Construction Heuristic followed by Local Search with custom `Move` implementations.